# Azure AD - External users invitation to SharePoint USING Powershell

Tags: azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

We would like to automate external user invitation in SharePoint. The manual process of what we are trying to achieve works but not the Powershell method.

**Manual Process:**
Share a sharepoint site to an email (e.g. a-guest-user@anyemail.com) by invitation. When the invited user accepts the invitation, user creates a Microsoft account, that will create an account in our Azure AD tenancy with a UPN **a-guest-user_anyemail.com#EXT#@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com**. The user can login subsequently using the email as the login id (**a-guest-user@anyemail.com**).

**Using Powershell Azure AD V2 modules**
Steps:

1. Create users using powershell command

   > **New-AzureADUser** -DisplayName "AGuest User" -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile -AccountEnabled $true -MailNickName "aguestuser"
   >   -UserPrincipalName "aguestuser@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com" -UserType "**Guest**" -OtherEmails "a-guest-user@anyemail.com"
2. Add the users to a relevant SharePoint group (using Add-SPOUser powershell command)
3. Users are emailed a link to the SharePoint site (for e.g. https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/myexternalsite)

Once this is done, this user can log in successfully using *aguestuser@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com*, but **not** using an email i.e. **a-guest-user@anyemail.com**

Does any one know how to allow the external user to login using their email account when provisioned using Powershell? Thank you

Comment: After a lot of trial and error, I have found out that this can be done using the New Azure B2B api (currently in preview) command New-AxureADMSInvitation. This process creates a local guest account in the current Azure AD and when the user accepts invitation they can log in using their existing Microsoft account or create a new password.

Answer (score 0):

The `New-AzureADUser` Powershell command only create a Azure AD user, it will not invite the external user.

To invite the external user, you can using the SharePoint client library and others write many similar scripts. For example, you can refer the script from [here](https://gist.github.com/markekraus/6fd7218b8eac225cbbf4d7c31018331b).

Comment: Thank you Fei Xue, but this script will not create the user in AzureAD  unless the user accepts the invitation, I want to create and send them their account information but also want them to login using their email account instead of the onmicrosoft account. Is this possible?

Comment: No, this is impossible. It is not able to mixing the **external user** with the accounts belongs your organization.  Please refer this document about more detail about external user from [What is an external user?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: Thanks, in principle when an external user is invited from SharePoint and the user accepts the invitation, a corresponding account is created for this account in the format a-guest-user_gmail.com#ext#.onmicrosoft.com in my Azure AD tenancy, I'm surprised why this cannot be done using powershell or API. We have 30,000 external users in our current SharePoint 2010 site and we want to retain document metadata when migrating to SharePoint online, it would be difficult to wait for the users to login to map their information.

Comment: If you want the external users account could be created before the user accept the invitation, you may submit the feedback from [here](https://office365.uservoice.com/).

Comment: It seems part of this is already possible by inviting the user in the new Azure API here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsinvitation?view=azureadps-2.0 however when the user logs in and creates a Microsoft account it says User is not found in directory. Looks like another dead end!

Comment: The command `New-​Azure​AD​MS​Invitation` works well for me when I invite the user which create a new Microsoft Account. I can authenticate  Azure AD with the new created Microsoft Account. Please make sure that external user follow the steps to complement the invitation.